# When do I use the initWithCoder: method?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

When am I supposed to use the initWithCoder: method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are supposed to use the `initWithCoder:` method when you are working with objects that have been archived. For example when you specifically use `NSKeyedUnarchiver` to create these archived objects or when you need to add custom initialization code to objects that are coming from a xib file.

Comment: the reason I ask is because i've created a subclass of UIScrollView, i'd like to set it position in the xib and grab that info and use it to set up the subclass, would I use initWithCoder: for something like that?

Answer (score 12):

Yes, if you are using a custom class in IB, then those objects are instantiated with the `initWithCode:` method. So, in your class you would override:

```
-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder {
    if (! (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]))
        return nil;

    // object has been created from IB... do initialization stuff here

    return self;
}
```